# Unable to get IDs (and of course value) of controls added dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I am just trying to add some dynamic controls to the SimpleQueryControl (which of course is a kind of Web Control and inherits all the methods accordingly). I dont know how to get the values of Child controls which I have added dynamically.

```
class RoomPickerQueryControl : SimpleQueryControl
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            EnsureChildControls();
            mColumnList.Visible = false;


        }



    }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTimeControl controlStartDate = new DateTimeControl();
        controlStartDate.LocaleId = 1053;
        controlStartDate.CssClassTextBox = "ms-long";
        controlStartDate.TimeZoneID = 1053;
        controlStartDate.LocaleId = 1053;
        controlStartDate.MinDate = DateTime.Now;
        controlStartDate.ID = "startDateTime";
        controlStartDate.Visible = true;
        controlStartDate.Enabled = true;
        controlStartDate.EnableViewState = true;
        this.Controls.Add(controlStartDate);




        base.OnInit(e);
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {

        base.CreateChildControls();


    }

    protected override int IssueQuery(string search, string groupName, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {

        //i'm unable to get the ids here
        DateTimeControl dt = (DateTimeControl) FindControlRecursive(this, "startDateTime");
 //i'm unable to get the ids here
        DateTimeControl dt3 = (DateTimeControl)FindControlRecursive(this.Page, "startDateTime");
 //i'm unable to get the ids here
        DateTimeControl controlStartDate = (DateTimeControl)this.FindControl("startDateTime");
 //i'm unable to get the ids here
        DateTimeControl controlEndDate = (DateTimeControl)this.FindControl("endDateTime");



        return rowCount;
    }


    public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control Root, string Id)
    {
        if (Root.ID == Id)
            return Root;
        foreach (Control Ctl in Root.Controls)
        {
            Control FoundCtl = FindControlRecursive(Ctl, Id);
            if (FoundCtl != null)
                return FoundCtl;
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);


    }
}
```

Comment: How do you want to use this value?

Comment: I want to use the value of the DateTimeControl upon IssueQuery method.

Comment: please provide your solution, where you are trying resolve those id´´s and its controls

Comment: I'm customizing people' picker control. I'm trying to add some controls to this picker control, from which I'll get the start date and end date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would recommend putting any controls you are creating in `CreateChildControls`.

Second, there are a couple ways you can get this working. The first is to use FindControl to get the reference to your control ([example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799154/get-value-from-programmatically-created-textbox-in-c/4799770#4799770)):

```
DateTimeControl dt = this.FindControl("startDateTime") as DateTimeControl;
```

An alternative is to make your `DateTimeControl` private member variables.

```
class RoomPickerQueryControl : SimpleQueryControl
{
   DateTimeControl controlStartDate;
   DateTimeControl controlEndDate;
   // more code...
```

Initialize your private member variables in CreateChildControls:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    base.CreateChildControls();

    // using our private class variable
    controlStartDate = new DateTimeControl();
    controlStartDate.LocaleId = 1053;
    // more code...
}
```

Then you can simply reference `controlStartDate` in your `IssueQuery` function.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm losing the date which I have selected upon the post back. How to retain the selected value upon post back of the control?

Comment: It is most likely because you are calling `IssueQuery` too early. You may want to call `IssueQuery` in an event (like a click event on a button) or maybe in OnPreRender. Here is some more info about the page lifecycle: http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2009/02/14/understanding-web-part-life-cycle/

Comment: IssueQuery is automatically called by the control and during the debugging this is the last method which is called. I must be missing something. Here is link to latest code as per you suggestions : http://pastebin.com/Htk6RaT1

Comment: A couple comments about the code... (1) you should use private member variables **OR** FindControl. (2) You define the public properties SelectedEndDate and SelectedStartDate but never use them anywhere? (3) Depending on how `DateTimeControl` is implemented saving to the ViewState won't be needed. Lastly, I would suggest getting a simpler case working first which may help in this more complicated case.

Answer (score 0):

Store a variable reference to them:

```
private DateTimeControl _controlStartDate;

Oninit(..)
{
   _controlStartDate = new DateTimeControl();
}
```

Comment: Hi Brian and thanks for reply. how can I avoid my DateTimeControl to save the value selected by user. I'm unable to save the selected date when a postback occurs.

Comment: The control value should be loaded  during viewstate; make sure your controls are created during Init or earlier though.  Alternatively, if you control implements IPostBackDataHandler, LoadPostData fires with the entire post tree, and you could get the inputted date there.